# Я использую PIXI JS и мой текст при зуме не сглаживаться

Tags: javascript, pixijs

```
const container = new PIXI.Container();

const style = {
  fontFamily: 'Arial',
  fontSize: 12,
  fill: 'white',
  align: 'center',
};

const machineText = new PIXI.Text(machineSprite.el.wide_name, style);
machineText.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);

if (machineSprite.rotation === 0 || machineSprite.rotation === Math.PI * 1) {
  machineText.position.set(0, machineSprite.el.coordinates.height / 2 + style.fontSize + 2);
} else if (machineSprite.rotation === Math.PI * 0.5 || machineSprite.rotation === Math.PI * 1.5) {
  machineText.position.set(0, machineSprite.el.coordinates.width / 2 + style.fontSize + 2);
}

container.addChild(machineText);

machineSprite.machineContainer.text = { obj: machineText, style };

machineSprite.machineContainer.addChild(container);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const machineText = new PIXI.Text(machineSprite.el.wide_name, style);
machineText.resolution = 2;
machineText.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);
```